# I just want to share xaml resources across more than 2 projects

Tags: wpf, xaml

Following image repesent that I want to.

[image]

*dgCommon classes has a no problem.

I want to share a xaml resource in CommonStyles directory. in Project 1, I added that xamls as **'add as link'** options in file open dialog window.

the following is a solution view of Project 1.

[image]

It loaded well in design time. Because a window which using these resources were showing properly state in design time.

But I can't run Project 1 due to Compile error. A compiler said that 'can't foudn \commonstyles\button.xaml''.

the following code is a the way to I load these resource xaml files.
(in App.xaml)

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <ResourceDictionary Source="CommonStyles\Button.xaml" />

...

</ResourceDictionary>
```

this tag worked properly in past time. (the time I locate a xaml file in specified folder, instead 'add to link')

I can't believe that there is a no simple solution for this issue.
I hope it just caused by my lack of googlibility.

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add as link` doesn't work quite well for xaml files. Try using a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) to reference the file in the common dll:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/CommonStyles;component/CommonStyles/Button.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

[More information on this issue here](http://devblog.ailon.org/devblog/post/2010/01/13/Writing-WPFSilverlight-compatible-code-Part-6-Adding-XAML-files-as-links.aspx)

Comment: 'Add as links' have lot of problem. so I decided to make a new wpf library dll. thanks.